# How do I change a text font style in a DIV box using CSS that's already using another style

Tags: css, html

I am trying to avoid using `<span style="font:10px Arial">` inline and just pull from my CSS since I know I am going to change this in phase two of my site.  At the end of my message tip I am trying to call .signature from CSS but it seems I can't break out of the bubble message part.

My code

```css
<style>
.tipbox {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}

.bubble{
    background-color: #727272;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #727272;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -55deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -55deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -55deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -55deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -55deg );
    width:  30px;
}

.message {
    float: center;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: Impact, Georgia, Serif;
}

.message::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}
         
}
.signature {
 font:10px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
 
</style>
```

```html
<div class="tipbox"><div class="bubble message">This is a very long line of text with a bunch of blah blah blah foo bar lah blah blah foo bar, see how I wrap around the box<span class="signature"> - love box</span></div></div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="tipbox"><div class="bubble message">This is a very long line of text with a bunch of blah blah blah foo bar lah blah blah foo bar, see how I wrap around the bo<span style="font:10px Arial"> - love box</span></div></div>
```

Comment: It's just a typo after the `message::before` you have an extra closer `}` .. that breaks the styles after

Comment: Faceplam... Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Simply add `display:block;` to the .signature section of your CSS.</strike>

On a second look, it seems to be the extra } that you have above the .signature section causing you issues. Remove this and it should work.